# How to make a certain p class the default p class (for Wordpress theme)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I made a custom p class for text in my Wordpress site. The trouble is, the CSS is coded in such way, if I put the properties from that p class on the default p - it messes up the layout.

So to get the text layout I want, I need to put  in front of every paragraph - and that's very annoying.

Is there a way to make that custom p class the default p by wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

You have to insert this into your functions.php file in order to replace all your `<p>` with something like `<p class="class">`.

```
function paragraph_replace($content){
    return preg_replace('/<p([^>]+)?>/', '<p$1 class="class">', $content);
}
add_filter('the_content', 'paragraph_replace');
```

Then you can easily address this class through CSS.

Comment: You should set the priority to something like 99, to ensure it's completed last.

Comment: thanks Kevin, one question should I replace $content with the name of the div, also 'the_content' and 'paragraph_replace' should those be renamed?

Comment: It works...but it still breaks the layout.

When I apply that p class in the WP editor, it lays out the text like its supposed. But when I add this PHP function, it breaks the entire page layout with it...